# Function returns nothing Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3

I have written a function, but it returns nothing. But when I execute that query separately, it works. Could you please help to understand why it happens?

Sql query is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS char_block (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    char_block_name CHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS string_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    char_name CHAR(64),
    char_block_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    char_description CHAR(256),
    boolean_value boolean NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO char_block VALUES(1, 'qqqqqqq:');
INSERT INTO char_block VALUES(2, 'wwwwwwwwwwww:');
INSERT INTO char_block VALUES(3, 'eeeeeeeeeeeee:');

INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(1, 'some string', 1, 'It means that blablabla...', FALSE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(2, 'hm', 1, 'Too long text...', FALSE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(3, 'no', 2, 'It means that blablabla...', FALSE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(4, 'pls', 2, 'Too long text...', FALSE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(5, 'bla', 2, 'Too long text...', FALSE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(6, 'bla1', 2, 'Too long text...', FALSE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(7, 'one more thing', 3, 'How to make...', TRUE);
INSERT INTO string_table VALUES(8, 'another thing', 3, 'It means...', TRUE);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_string_table()
  RETURNS table(id INTEGER, 
  char_name CHAR(64),
  char_description  CHAR(256),
  boolean_value boolean,
  char_block_name CHAR(64)) AS
$func$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('
  SELECT 
  string_table.id, 
  string_table.char_name, 
  string_table.char_description, 
  string_table.boolean_value, 
  char_block.char_block_name
FROM 
  string_table, 
  char_block
WHERE 
  string_table.char_block_id = char_block.id
ORDER BY string_table.id;');
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, if I run

```
 SELECT 
      string_table.id, 
      string_table.char_name, 
      string_table.char_description, 
      string_table.boolean_value, 
      char_block.char_block_name
    FROM 
      string_table, 
      char_block
    WHERE 
      string_table.char_block_id = char_block.id
    ORDER BY string_table.id;
```

... it will work, but if I run

```
SELECT * FROM get_all_string_table();
```

it will return empty table.

Could you please explain why it happens?

I am using postgresql 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your function. `EXECUTE` only runs the statement, but does not generate a result.

You also don't need the `format()` call for a "static" statement and PL/pgSQL is also not needed. The following will work just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_string_table()
  RETURNS table(id INTEGER, 
  char_name CHAR(64),
  char_description  CHAR(256),
  boolean_value boolean,
  char_block_name CHAR(64)) AS
$func$
  SELECT 
  string_table.id, 
  string_table.char_name, 
  string_table.char_description, 
  string_table.boolean_value, 
  char_block.char_block_name
FROM 
  string_table, 
  char_block
WHERE 
  string_table.char_block_id = char_block.id
ORDER BY string_table.id;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

To make your orginal version using `execute` and `format()` work you would need to use:

```
return query EXECUTE format(....);
```

instead of just `execute format (...)`

---

Unrelated, but: you most probably do **not** want to use the `CHAR` datatype. It is a fixed length data type, which means that anything you store in it, will be padded with spaces to the defined length.

You should use `varchar` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I need `format` in the future , I will pass char_block_name to the function.

Comment: @user565447 To support a parameter you do not need `format` or dynamic SQL